# Consider a particular system like harmonic oscillator can we do the calculations for the given system using micro-canonical ensemble?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator

Consider a particular system like harmonic oscillator can we do the calculations for thermodynamic variables in the given system like energy, pressure and entropy etc using micro-canonical ensemble or grand canonical ensemble and obtain the same results?

Comment: Are you asking if the thermodynamics of one harmonic oscillator is the same in the micro and grand canonical ensemble?

Comment: @Giorgiop Yes, indeed!

Comment: @GiorgioP Now I understand that we are using canonical ensemble because of the complexities of the problem as for a system other than harmonic oscillator, we may not use the canonical and grand canonical ensemble. Now the real question arises that what are the systems where we can use the microcanonical and grand canonical ensembles? Can you please give me an example of it?